# Vue 3 - Deeply nested reactive object prop cannot be watched or computed on

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am using vue-use to retrieve a deeply nested reactive prop from session storage. The ui updates successfully, but the computed and watch functions aren't updating. Below is my code:

```js
const defaultState = {
  myComp: [{ isSelected: true }]
};

const state = useSessionStorage("settings", defaultState, {
  mergeDefaults: true,
});

watch(state.value.myComp[0].isSelected, (old, newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue);
});

const misc = computed(() =>
  console.log(state.value.myComp[0].isSelected)
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the `deep` option to your watch:

```
watch(state.value.myComp[0], (old, newValue) => {
  console.log(newValue);
}, { deep: true });
```

More information [here](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html#deep-watchers)

Comment: Regarding the `computed` property - I don't think it will run again the `console.log`  method when the state changes